# Is there any upper-bound function such as $\frac{k}{x}$ for monotonically decreasing functions?

Tags: functions, upper-lower-bounds, monotone-functions

Could you please tell me if the following statement is true?

"Any monotonically decreasing function can be upper-bounded by function $f(x)=\frac{K}{x}$, i.e, if $g(x)$ is a monotonically decaying function then there is a positive real $K$ such that $g(x)≤f(x)$ for $x>0$."

If so, is there any proof for this statement or similar ones that can be found? Any references would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Maybe $g(x) = 1$?

Comment: @peterwhy Thank you for your response. Sorry, maybe I could not explain the problem clearly. The problem is that based on numerical simulation it seems function $f(x)=\frac{k}{x}$ can be considered as an upper bound for any monotonically decaying function g(x) for $x>0$. I am not looking to find g(x), I am looking to find proof for the former statement.

Comment: As a counterexample try $1/\ln x$ or,  if you need the function to be defined  for $x>0$, take $1/\ln(x+1)$.

Comment: For a $g(x)$, if there were such $f(x) = K/x$, then the $K$ would satisfy $K\ge xg(x)$ for all $x>0$. To find a counterexample, find a monotonically decreasing $g(x)$ that gives unbounded $xg(x)$. For example, $1$, $1/\ln x$, $1/\ln(x+1)$, $1/\sqrt{x}$, ...

Comment: @peterwhy Thank you. But what if I limit the domain, i.e., $x \in [a,b]$. Is there any procedure to find a domain in which the statement holds?

Comment: @BruoKrams Thank you. But what if I limit the domain, i.e., x∈[a,b]. Is there any procedure to find a domain in which the statement holds?

Comment: @Amin That would be to find an upper bound of $xg(x)$ for $x\in[a,b]$, then call it $K$.

Comment: @peterwhy I got the point. Thank you so much.